# Horizontal paging in iOS with UITableView like memory design?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, paging, scroll-paging

[image]

- White boxes represent items in an `NSArray`.
- Swiping from a directing changes the indexes and update the items accordingly. (not scrolling 1 by 1 but like changing pages. So, changing all 4 items at every swipe)
- In this example, there are approximately 20 items in this array and we are in the second page. It currently shows item at index 4,5,6,7.
- There can be more items.
- I don't want to create at least 20 items and keep them at a far `frame` (`CGRect`).
- I want to have a scheme like UITableView, where it creates approximately 6 items for infinite number of items if the tableview can show only 4 items at a time.
- So, I plan to have 5 or 6 items for 6+ items and just update the item's contents (item = white boxes) according to real data at that index of `NSArray`

Is there a quick and ready way to do this easily or may there be a better way to do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using tableview you can use scrollview with page control.
try using this link :https://github.com/cwalcott/UIScrollView-Paging/tree/buttons

Comment: `UITableView` is actually a `UIScrollView` subclass